# How to limit registers by two columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Well, I want to limit the query result with the next rule: each 'intervalo' only can have 4 enterprises with the same date, so the query below should throw, for example, the 4 first rows and not 5. As you can see, there are more than 4 enterprises with the same date at the same interval. How can I solve this?

**Full list**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWXxN.png)

**Query**

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM entregas 
        JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idIntervaloHorario= intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
        GROUP BY entregas.fechaCita, intervaloshorarios.intervaloHorario <= 4
        ORDER BY entregas.fechaCita asc
    ;');
```

**Query result from full list**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFxcT.png)

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean by "i want to show 4 if it exists" ?

Comment: Ignore ''if it exists", i will update the question. I want to show 4.

Comment: show 4 of what? can you point us to a specific example from your result list?

Comment: I have posted two images with list before query and after query, can you see it?

Comment: Yes. Still unclear to me what you're asking to achieve (count only records with more than 4 identical "fecha" values?). Try to explain better so we'll be able to assist.

Comment: Well, look at the full list, for example, the first 5 rows have the same 'Fecha' and 'Intervalo'. I want to limit the rows with the same 'Fecha' and 'Intervalo' at 4 as max. So, the 4 row shouldn't appear in this case.

Comment: But your result only includes 1 out of the 5 rows ("Herba").

Comment: You're right, althogh result only includes 1 out of the 5 rows ("Herba"), I can only have 4 different enterprises for each 'intervalo' with the same 'fecha' as max

Comment: This is bad answer, i will reedit.